# Comparison of worth to the Father between Jesus and His people

Tags: life-of-jesus

Who is more important to God the Father:

1. Jesus His Only Son?
2. The people Jesus died for?

This was posed to me today by a friend and I have no idea how to answer it.

If 1. is chosen, then it would suggest that it would be stupid for God to sacrifice His only beloved Son for people who don't deserve it. In other words the sacrifice of Jesus just would not have happened. e.g. If I have 2 cars of the same model, a good one and a not so good one, I would ALWAYS take parts from the bad one to put in the good one (if needed), never the other way around.

If 2. then what does that say about God the Father and His love for Jesus?

Answer (score 4):

This question is based on bit of faulty logic which isn't really appropriate to the scenario. Firstly, the analogy of a car isn't appropriate when it's applied to people. The car analogy wouldn't be used, for example, if you were trying to compare the importance of your wife versus your children.

Secondly, two important points are forgotten:

1. Jesus is a willing participant in this. God the Son *chose* to descend from heaven and pay the price to redeem mankind.
2. Jesus and the Father are also in some sense one. God the Father is not just sacrificing his son, he is also sacrificing himself.

This issue is not a logical economic transaction and should not be approached that way. People do 'stupid' things all the time to save the ones they love.